# how to pass dynamic xpath in protractor and cucumber using typescript

Tags: typescript, xpath, protractor, cucumber

I want to dynamically pass a parameter in my xpath. for page objects I have created a class and it is called in my step definition. please see below

below is my code and the error message

````
//this is my page object
export class accountPage{

    accountNo: string;
    public accountNumberLabel = element(by.xpath('//span[text()=" '+this.accountNo+' "]'))



    async getAccountNumberLabel(): Promise<string>{
        return await Promise.resolve(this.accountNumberLabel.getText());
    }   
}

//and this is my step definition

const accountpage = new new accountPage();

Then('I assert the row  {string} for {string}',async(account_number, account_value)=>{
    accountpage.accountNo = account_number;
    await browser.sleep(2000);
    if(searchKey.includes("account_number")){
        assert.equal(await accountpage.getAccountNumberLabel(),account_value);
    }
});```

//I am receiving an error 
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //span[text()=" undefined "])

when I read the value console.log(accountpage.accountNo) it is returning correct value
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1 :

```
`this.accountNo` is undefined.
```

Issue 2 :

Use template literals to concatenate strings.

```
element(by.xpath(`//span[text()='${this.accountNo}']`))
```

Check you have two spaces in the console. I mean before and after undefined

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //span[text()=" undefined "]
```

Comment: thanks Bharat. I have used the locator as suggested 

but it is still giving the error as 

NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //span[text()='undefined'])

Comment: Yes because of issue 1 this.accountNo is undefined

Comment: Your account_number is not passed to your pages file correctly. Can you console.log account_number in your step definition and check if this is undefined

Comment: when I console.log(account_number) it is displaying the correct account number

Comment: That is clear account number is undefined in pages file. You can try to give a hard coded account number in pages and check if getText for that element is working. Later you have to fix the framework

Comment: If I print the class object using console.log(accountpage) then i can see the required account_number and the correct xpath is also getting printed but when the element is used then it is not taking acc number. not sure why is this weird behaviour. 

If I do hard code then it is taking the hard coded value. might be framework issue. thanks Bharat

Comment: Welcome Irfan. Close this question and open a new question for framework issues. I can help out if you give me the git repo link.